# to use /users/xx twitter API, do I need to subscribe still?

Tags: twitter

If I just want to use /users/by/username/xxx, /users/xxx/tweets api, do I need subscription still?

It looks like subscription is for search API mainly. I have no intention to use search tweet.

Apart from the fact I don't need 'search api', they seem to really expensive to use.

- Pricing for the elevated tiers of the Search Tweets: 30-day endpoint
  start at $149/month for 500 requests, while pricing for the Search
  Tweets: Full-archive endpoint starts at $99/month for 100 requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no need to subscribe to the premium API to use the v2 users lookup API.